# Multiply Rasters with Scalar Numbers as Input in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

I built a little model in the QGIS modelbuilder which uses the raster calculator with the command

> gt(a,threshold)

I need to run the model with varying thresholds from 2 to 30 so it would be great to create a *Number* input in the model for this threshold so I'm asked for its value when starting the model, but the raster calculator only accepts rasters as inputs.

Maybe someone has an idea how to get around this problem? For example by generating a raster containing only the threshold value in every cell in a previous step if there is an easy way to do this?